# Disabling a Feature does not clear the content item from the admin menu

Tags: orchardcms

I have a custom content item developed for enquiry forms, with following migration

```
             ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Bt Enquiry Page", cfg => cfg
            .WithPart("TitlePart")
            .WithPart("AutoroutePart")
             .WithPart("AutoroutePart", builder => builder
              .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.AllowCustomPattern", "true")
              .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.AutomaticAdjustmentOnEdit", "false")
              .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.PatternDefinitions", "[{Name:'Title', Pattern: '{Content.Slug}', Description: 'my-page'}]")
              .WithSetting("AutorouteSettings.DefaultPatternIndex", "0"))
            .WithPart("MenuPart")
            .WithPart("TagPart")
            .WithPart("BodyPart")
            .WithPart("CommonPart")
            .WithPart("EnquirySettingPart")
            .Creatable()
            .Indexed()
            );
```

For some reason when I disable the module feature, the custom content item "Bt Enquiry Page" does not disappear from the admin menu, which means I can create the instance of the content item even if the feature is disabled. is that the default behavior? am I missing something, can anybody shed some lights.

-George

Comment: I believe this is the default behaviour. You can always delete the content type yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a default behavior.

Orchard does not roll back any changes made through migrations when you disable a module. Migrations can get fairly complex and do things that cannot be easily rolled back automatically (or even shouldn't).

But you're free to do the cleanup yourself by either:

- deleting the obsolete content type from Dashboard (`Content -> Content Types` in <= 1.6 or `Content Definition` in >=1.7 up)
- hooking up `IFeatureEventHandler` and using `Enabled/Disabled` events to perform cleanup tasks

Comment: More than the difficulty of rolling back migrations, it is often not desirable to remove the content types and items: items may have been enhanced to use other parts, and may still be useful.

Comment: Exactly. Should also add that migrations always "alter" content types (which implicitly creates one if it doesn't exist). Without some custom flagging you can't tell which feature was the initial creator.